# Using ng-if inside ng-repeat with angular field not working

Tags: angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to show/hide each image in case `equipment.state` value, 
in my case `equipment.state` is equal to `'true'` or `'false'` !

```
<div ng-repeat="equipment in listeequipements" class="list-group"  >
<img src="images/m_next_all.png"    ng-if="{{equipment.state}}" width="32px"></div>
```

my code returns following error:

```
*Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column
2 of the expression [{{equipment.state}}] starting at [{equipment.state}}].*
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: Working Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/B1JyunKh3BdsnBpBLN1s/

You don't need these brackets. You can just write `equipment.state` inside your `ng-if=""`.

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="equipment in listeequipements" class="list-group"  >
    <img src="images/m_next_all.png" ng-if="equipment.state" width="32px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's work for me ! thanks.
 .Another mistake present in my code wil help others.
in php code : must be like this

```
if($nbtotal>0){$suivant=true;}else{$suivant=false;}

    $data[] = array(
        "id_equipement"     => $rows[id_equipement],
        "designation"       => $rows[designation],
        "state"           => $suivant
    );
```